# local storage compatibility in chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I m developing a **chrome extension** and i want to know that from which version of **google chrmoe** it started supporting **local storage** and **session storage** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage in Chrome 4

sessionStorage in Chrome 5

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage ( towards the bottom )

I dont think any one still uses such early versions of Chrome.

T.